# Karma to exit on Browserify bundle error?

Tags: karma-runner, browserify

When running my unit tests, we preprocess our files using Browserify. Occasionally, we have bundle errors, i.e:

```
ERROR [framework.browserify]: bundle error
```

Karma does report the error but does not exit the process. Can I configure karma to fail if it reports a Browserify bundle error?

Answer (score 1):

Actually setting karma.failOnEmptySuite to true has the desired effect I was looking for.